# How to authenticate a user in spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I'm not understanding how this code works especially the OncePerRequestFilter class what's the purpose of this class I''ve pasted the code available to me.

```
public class AuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter{

private final LoginService loginService;

private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(AuthenticationFilter.class);

public AuthenticationFilter(final LoginService loginService) {
    super();
    this.loginService = loginService;
}

@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response, final FilterChain filterChain)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    final String xAuth = request.getHeader("X-Authorization");
```

Comment: See the example of spring boot: https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/

Comment: I want to delete this question can you tell me how to delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Authenticate and Authorization are two different terms.
1. Authenticate : you are the one who you are claiming.
2. Authorization : What are you allowed to do.

Assumption : your question is for authorize : " I want to authorize specific user based on rest api's".

configure **http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/products").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")**

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/products").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')").anyRequest().permitAll().and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/hello").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')").anyRequest().permitAll().and()
            .formLogin().loginPage("/login").usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password").and()
            .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout").and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403").and()
            .csrf();
}
```

refer for full code : https://github.com/Roshanmutha/SpringSecurityJDBC/blob/master/src/main/java/com/roshantest/WebSecurityConfig.java